# How to build cv2 binding

Tags: c++, python-3.x, opencv, cmake

I have followed the [opencv doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html) for creating my own bindings.

I run the file `gen2.py` which generated some header files:

```
./
../
pyopencv_generated_enums.h
pyopencv_generated_funcs.h
pyopencv_generated_include.h
pyopencv_generated_modules_content.h
pyopencv_generated_modules.h
pyopencv_generated_types_content.h
pyopencv_generated_types.h
pyopencv_signatures.json
```

How should I build this?
I tried running `cmake CMakeLists.txt` directly in `/opencv/modules/python` but some defines were not found.

and I tried on re-building running `cmake CMakeLists.txt` in `/opencv/` , where I got:

```
  FATAL: In-source builds are not allowed.

         You should create a separate directory for build files.
```

I think both approaches were quite wrong, but I haven't found any doc explaining how to build using the generated headers.

I'm using `opencv 4.5.5` which I cloned and built.

**EDIT**

I found this in `/source/opencv/modules/python/bindings/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
string(REPLACE ";" "\n" opencv_hdrs_ "${opencv_hdrs}")
file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/headers.txt" "${opencv_hdrs_}")
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${cv2_generated_files}
    COMMAND "${PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE}" "${PYTHON_SOURCE_DIR}/src2/gen2.py" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/headers.txt"
    DEPENDS "${PYTHON_SOURCE_DIR}/src2/gen2.py"
            "${PYTHON_SOURCE_DIR}/src2/hdr_parser.py"
            # not a real build dependency (file(WRITE) result): ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/headers.txt
            ${opencv_hdrs}
    COMMENT "Generate files for Python bindings and documentation"
)
```

I guess I have to add the path to my headers in `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/headers.txt` just not sure how to get the value of  `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`

**EDIT 2**

As proposed by @berak, I tried `CMAKE_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=my/path`
this seems to get me really close to what I need.

It compiles my sources and generates the `.so` files as `libopencv_xxx.so` and saves them in my `/usr/local/lib`

(when running `nm` on it I see my class and method)

BUT! when I `import cv2` in a script I don't achieve to load my module.
I tried `print(cv2.__dict__)` and `grep`ed on it, but it's not there.

Any clue on how to add the compiled modules into my python-opencv installation?

Comment: This might not help, but in case you haven't seen it.  You could try https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/ which seems to have directions on building opencv-python.  I'm not sure if you can get the exact version but if you're flexible it might be easier.  This doesn't actually answer your question of course, but having struggled with OpenCV I know it can be painful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much documentation on how to create a bind (at least I only found [this](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html), which is very helpful but doesn't have all the information).

First, your module **must** use the following tree structure (I did everything with cmake):

```
.
src
└── modules
    └── your_module
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── include
        │   └── opencv2
        │       └── your_module_bind_lib.hpp
        └── src
            └── your_module_bind_lib.cpp
```

An example of my `CMakeLists.txt` (this of course may change according to your project):

```
set(the_description "yourModule LIB")
ocv_define_module(your_module opencv_imgproc WRAP python)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Then I cloned OpenCV with

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
```

Make a build folder

```
mkdir wherever/build
```

And run the following command for `cmake`

```
cd wherever/build
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/project_from_previous_tree/src/modules/ -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_apps=OFF -D BUILD_DOCS=OFF -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/  your_opencv_location/opencv/
make -j8
make install
```

In that command the only "special" thing was `DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` (thanks to @berak for the idea).

And then? what happens in python level?

Make sure your python installation actually points to the built opencv, or use something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/python-3.8')
import cv2
```

where `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/python-3.8'` is where the generated `.so` is located in my PC.

With this you will be able to use things like

```
cv2.my_cpp_function()
cv2.my_cpp_class.some_method()
...
```

Where `my_cpp` stuff was declared and defined in the module project following the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html) and can "easily" have OpenCV typed objects as parameters.

Et voila, now you can use your c++ functions in python.

Notice that this solution does not do **any** modification to the opencv directory cloned from Git.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to run gen2.py manually, cmake will do this for you at some stage, internally.

since you seem to be on some linux, rather [follow the build steps here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html), this will also generate python bindings, the gist of it is:

- make a special "build folder" and cd into it (dont try to build in the src folder, you'll never be able to clean anything up)
- run `cmake <some args> path_to_src_folder` (or better even - cmake-gui) , check if `python3` shows up in the "To be build" section of the output
- run `make install`

Comment: And where do I add the .txt file with the new headers? (needed by gen2.py)

Comment: you dont. again, leave it to cmake to generate that one, too

Comment: "for creating my own bindings."  as long as those are inside the opencv src tree, cmake should find them. did you add a new module, or something ?

Comment: yes , I have a complete project of image treatment functions in C++ and I want to add bindings for python... And it feels wrong to add code to the opencv folder

Comment: "And it feels wrong to add code to the opencv folder" dont be too afraid of that. well, you still can point cmake to your very own folder adding `CMAKE_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/my/folder` . in any way, make sure [it contains a CMakeLists.txt like this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/4.x/modules/plot/CMakeLists.txt)  (`WRAP python` is the key here)

Comment: Check my last edit :)

Comment: i would not want to mess with *that*. but, since you're asking, `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} `is `build/modules/python_bindings_generator` . in other words, whatever you do there, it will get overwritten

Comment: again, NOT RECOMMENDED (!!!), but maybe you can get away with adding your headers to `${opencv_hdrs}` there. (though it's unclear, how it would compile & link the resp. cpp files, if you go "off the grid" like that)

Comment: I have a new edit, I'm getting close :)